# paymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier NSInvalidArgumentException error

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I am trying out stripe payment integration in iOS app using [this](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios#applepay) link.

I am getting the following error:

```
    +[Stripe paymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier:amount:currency:description:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10ecc73d0
2014-10-13 12:04:50.029 stripeDemoApplePay[2507:71067] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Stripe paymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier:amount:currency:description:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10ecc73d0'
```

Following is the code where am getting this error:

```
    - (IBAction)beginPayment:(id)sender {
    NSString *merchantId = @"my merchant id";
    NSInteger price = 10;
//    NSUInteger *numberOfShirts = ;
    NSDecimalNumber *amt = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:price exponent:0 isNegative:NO];;
    PKPaymentRequest *paymentRequest = [Stripe paymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier:merchantId
                                                                             amount:amt
                                                                           currency:@"USD"
                                                                        description:@"Premium Llama Food"]; //ERROR LINE
    [paymentRequest setRequiredShippingAddressFields:PKAddressFieldPostalAddress];
    [paymentRequest setRequiredBillingAddressFields:PKAddressFieldPostalAddress];
```

Where am I getting wrong? how do I solve this?

Comment: I am having the same problem after following the Stripe iOS tutorial. https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios

Answer (score 1):

It looks like apple changed the way they implemented the payment request, and stripe followed suite. Below is the new stripe method. Make sure you have the most up to date stripe SDK.

```
+ (PKPaymentRequest *)paymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier:(NSString *)merchantIdentifier;
```

Take a look at the PKPaymentRequest documentation. The final summary item is now the amount.

Comment: Including Stripe+ApplePay.h doesn't seem to help

Comment: I edited my answer with what I think is now the problem mcassano. The tutorials, may not be up to date with the new method yet though. I know they are working on it now though.

Comment: Yeap, thank you, I came here to say this.  If you view the Example Xcode project in stripe-ios you see they use:  PKPaymentRequest *paymentRequest = [Stripe paymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier:merchantId];

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue because of the compile-time constants that Stripe is checking for at the top of their ApplePay category:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000 && defined(STRIPE_ENABLE_APPLEPAY)
```

without those the method you are trying to call will not be available

[Stripe+ApplePay category on github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Stripe/ApplePay/Stripe%2BApplePay.m#L9)